# ReportViewer inside UpdatePanel not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using report viewer in asp.net code to display SSRS report on page but when I click on 
View Report button then whole page is get refreshed and I then put Report viewer in update panel of Ajax but its not working properly.
Like when I click on view Report button then page not get refreshed but after changing report parameters data not change in pie chart and display the same for all parameters.
Also I have put the parameters and button controls outside of report viewer control and even its not working and getting the same records in pie chart report.
So Please is there any possibility to put Report viewer inside Update panel.

Thanks,
Deepak Garg

Comment: Please show you aspx code with update panel and codebihind which affects the Reportviewer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the control inside of an update panel, you could set the AsyncRendering property to true.  This should prevent the control from causing postbacks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You could also put the control inside an iframe on your page with AsyncRendering false and manage that yourself if necessary.